# How to translate Solr JSON response into HTML while JSON is different every time

Tags: javascript, json, solr

I am using Solr 4 for searching in a java web application.Solr produces a JSON response from which i have to extract search results and translate them into html so user can read that.
I know one solution but it seems dumb an I think there must be  intelligent ideas.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "fl": "id,title",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "solr",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 3,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Solr cookbook"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Solr results"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Solr perfect search"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After that i eval this text as:

```
var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");
```

To generate html page i can use either

```
 <script>
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = obj.response.docs[1].id
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = obj.response.docs[1].title
</script>

or

document.write(obj.response.docs[1].id);
```

But limitation is that every time solr gives  response with different object structure i.e. an object may have age feild but other can not have because it depends on query.

---

> I want to use a sigle JSP page to display search results(like Google)
>   for all search queries

---

is it possible to write a single code segment which works for any possible search results with different schema.

Javascript stops working after encountering any error which is likely in my case. that's also problem.if I use for loop to traverse the object hierarchy it is highly error -prone.

Is it possible with a single view page Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using [ajax-solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) - *A JavaScript framework for creating user interfaces to Solr*

Comment: thanx a lot for your help.I am using ajax-solr

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Velocity templating which is readily supported in Solr - instead of extracting data from the JSON and rendering the HTML via JS.

Docs [**here**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter)